# Directive not responding to changes in scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following directive:

```
  <span ng-show="{{ save_state == 'saved' }}"> Saved </span>
  <span ng-show="{{ save_state == 'saving' }}"> Saving </span>
  <span ng-show="{{ save_state == 'error' }}"> Error </span>
```

These callbacks are called at various time:

```
var saving = function() {
    $scope.save_state = "saving";
    $scope.$apply();
};
var saved = function() {
    $scope.save_state = "saved";
    $scope.$apply();
};
var error = function(err) {
    alert(err);
    $scope.save_state = "error";
    $scope.$apply();
};
```

**and I also have this statement for debugging**

```
<span> {{ save_state == 'saving' }} </span>
```

**For some reason, even what the span tag above shows `true`, the "Saving" span tag does not show. Same for "error". Why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are interpolating `{{ }}` the contents of the `ng-show` Directive:

```
ng-show="{{ save_state == 'saved' }}"
```

`ng-show` requires that you provide a valid Angular Expression.:

```
ng-show="save_state == 'saved'"
```

Comment: I don't think it's quite right to say "since it is an Angular directive": some directives require a string, and allow interpolation by {{ }}, and then will watch the contents of the attribute for changes. In this case, `ngShow` requires an [Angular expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) and not a string.